# Angular - Obeservable not working correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have the following code that is not working correctly.

I have a service, which offers registration for a user.

```
register(firstname: string, lastname: string, email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
    let body = {firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, email: email, password: password};
    
    this.http.post(this.base_url + "api/register/user/", body)
    .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            if((data as any).status == 'success') {
                return Observable.of(true);
            }
        },
        (error) => {
           return Observable.of(false);
    });
    return Observable.of(false);
  }
```

The register method is working correctly since the API where I'm registering the users is returning "success". The problem is when I'm calling it as follows:

```
registerUser(e) {
    
    ...
    
    let isRegistered = false;
    
    this.userService.register(firstname, lastname, email, password).subscribe(register => isRegistered = register);
    
    
    if(isRegistered) {
        console.log("isRegistered = true");
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("isRegistered = false");
        return false;
    }
  }
```

I'm also importing the necessary modules:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

"isRegister" is remaining false and as a result, the page is not redirecting to the home page.

Does anyone have an idea where the problem could be?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6):

The `isRegistered` value will always be `false` because you are treating an asynchronous operation like a synchronous one. Basically the check `if (isRegistered)` will run before you have acquired the value from your service. In order to avoid this, you have to move the checks inside of the subscription success callback:

```
this.userService
  .register(firstname, lastname, email, password)
  .subscribe(isRegistered => {
    if (isRegistered) {
      this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
```

In this way you will be sure that `isRegistered`'s value has been set by the result of the service call.

Your `register()` function also has a flaw - you will always return an `Observable` of `false`. You probably want to return the result of the HTTP request. You should `.map()` the result of the HTTP response to a `Boolean` and subscribe when using the service.

```
register(firstname: string, lastname: string, email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {
  const body = { firstname, lastname, email, password };

  return this.http.post(this.base_url + 'api/register/user/', body)
    .map(data => {
        if((data as any).status === 'success') {
            return Observable.of(true);
        } else {
            return Observable.of(false);
        }
    })
    .catch(() => Observable.of(false));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm having another problem with this approach now, the http is not making any request inside the service. I'm getting the following error: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error".

Comment: The error cannot be caused by my changes, since I didn't change the parameters passed to the service in any way. Can you share more of the `registerUser()` code? Also check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180634/i-get-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error-instead-of-actu - you might have CORS issues.

Comment: The registerUser() method only takes the email, password, ... from the html. Can you please take a look at the register() method of the UserService that I've posted above. Do you now any better way on how I could make the http post request or is the method fine?

Comment: I made an edit because I spotted a flaw in your `register()` function. However, the HTTP call looks correct. The only thing I can think of is if the `this.base_url` value is an invalid URL. Can you please share it?

Comment: The base url is as follows: private base_url = "http://localhost:5001/"; . I also made the change in the register() method, but I'm getting the following error now: " Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'."

Comment: Oops, I've forgotten to change the `.subscribe()` to `.map()`. I've re-written the whole function body. Please check if it works now.

Comment: You are probably having the server on a different port than the Angular app served by `ng serve`. If that is the case, I'm sure this is a CORS issue since for the browser `localhost:5001` and `localhost:{OTHER_PORT}` are different origins no matter these are on the same machine.

Comment: You are right, it is a CORS problem :/ I'm having them inside two docker containers and they have different ports. The server is running in Slim PHP. Thank you for your answers man ;)