# Http request and response in Angular 2.0

Tags: angular, http, connection-timeout

I am stuck in a problem, where my webservice (written in Spring boot) takes 5-6 minutes for a http response.
I send a http post request from angular but chrome waits for only 2 minutes gives me a null response since there was no response from server.
But server will give a response after 5 minutes.
So how can I implement this scenario, since I think my http connection closes after 2 minutes and I want to extend it till 5-6 minutes.
FYI
I have already used rxjs timeout function but it doesn't work, the default timeout of 2 mins always wins.
Thank you

Comment: did you use promises?

Comment: Check your server code performance

Comment: Add your code of Angular.

Comment: @SuvethanNantha yes i used promise but its of no use

Comment: @DarshilGada is your issue is not resolved yet? what about the solution I gave ain't it working?

Comment: @Vikas yes it worked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is not with `chrome` You must be using **[`Proxying support`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)** in which dev-server makes use **[`http-proxy-middleware package`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy)** and the proxy options provided in this package is from underlying **[`http-proxy library`](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#options).**
one among them is

> **proxyTimeout**:
>
> timeout (in millis) when the proxy receives no response

The default value is ~120 seconds and a new request is made if the `backend` fails to respond within the stipulated time.
overriding the default timeout with `"timeout":360000` in the proxy config file will resolve the issue.

```
{
  "/api/*": {
     "target":  {
       "host": "localhost",
       "protocol": "http:",
       "port": 8080
     },
     "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "debug",
     "timeout":360000
  
  }
}
```

you also need to enable Cross-Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service using  **[`@CrossOrigin`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)** annotation in your controller link.The `@CrossOrigin` is used to allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) so that our angular application running on a different server can consume these APIs from a browser.

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping({"/api"})
    public class UserController {
           ......
}
```

I assume your angular is running on `port` 4200 with above configuration you can consume your API's.

**NOTE**: The `proxy` configuration is intended to proxy calls when running the dev server via `ng serve`. After you run `ng build` you are responsible for the web server and its configurations

Comment: Its giving me HPE_INVALID_CHUNK_SIZE, when I try to use the data that I got from my webService. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: Hi if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.