# "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error" Angular

Tags: angular, rest, angular4-forms, angular4-httpclient

I try use service httpClient post but I have this error:

[image]

code service:

```
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

              Login(data)
              {

                let headers: any = new HttpHeaders();
                headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

                return this.http.post('link api',data,{headers: headers})
                .subscribe(res => console.log(res),err => { console.log(err);});

              }
```

and I try add responseType: 'text' but also error ... I use angular 4

Comment: It might be a silly question, but are your sure your 'link api' is a well formed url ?

Comment: Yes link api is a well formed url ...

Comment: any help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see, it's not an error from the http client directly, but from your server.

In a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180634/i-get-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error-instead-of-actu), the problem was coming from CORS and the fact that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header was not correctly added in case the server response did not have a 20X or 30X status.

Did you check your server and log the call ?

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

In the backend code, If you are using Spring boot add an annotation @Crossorigin right above the CRUD API call method.