# Angular:Post request becomes options

Tags: angular, rest, angular6

I'm using angular 6, httpClient, trying to login, no token required, just a username and a password, can't modify the server.

`login.ts`

```
  onLogin() {
    this.authService.login(this.email, this.password).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

`auth service`

```
  login(username, password) {
    const data = {
      username: username,
      password: password
    };

    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post(this.login_url, data, { headers: headers });
  }
```

There are plenty of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180634/i-get-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error-instead-of-actu) but those were for angularjs and I'm using angular 6, some answers gave articles to read with no practical coding answer, and some says to change the header, but as far as I can tell from my postman tests, the server only accepts `'Content-Type', 'application/json'` And it's working perfectly on postman. When I do it in angular, my post request, becomes options.

Some even say that to avoid CORS, you should setup an interceptor, but that's for when you have a token, no? you save it in localStorage and then you use it, I don't have a token. The server `X-Session` in the header.

Some say, to create a proxy, `package.json`,

```
`"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json",`
```

`proxyconfig.json`

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "example.com",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

And the `login_url` in `auth service` would point to the rest endpoint without `/example/api`. I also tried that, it's not working either.

Some says, you have to edit the webserver, to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, I'd like not to do that, if possible. If not, I'll contact my company and ask them to do it. I'd like a solution using angular 6.

Comment: one possible reason could be if your clientside URL (login page )and server-side URL are not same domain then, the browser sends one `option` request every time to the back-end to check if the request is allowed, once the option is passed then it sends the post request.

Comment: @anand how? by using an interceptor? could you give an example?

Comment: is your api is on node?

Comment: @Sajeetharan no, php5, apache server, laravel, centos running on firebase, I don't control the remote server, it belongs to my company, so can't make changes to the server or api

Comment: it could be a change that needs to be done on the remote api, you just need to use postman and see if the request is working

Comment: @Sajeetharan everything is working on postman but in the browser i see `Cross - Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://example.com. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

Comment: could you try run your application in incognito mode

Comment: @Sajeetharan just tried, same error, I guess I need to contact them