# NativeScript HTTP Get Request not working. Android Version issue?

Tags: android, http, get, request, nativescript

I've been working on a node.js backend application. Now I want to start programming the frontend but I got struggle executing the HTTP Requests. I have got a physical tablet Samsung Galaxy Tab Active2 for the tests, but the simple GET request doesn't work on this tablet with Android version 9.

I tried to run the exact same app with the HTTP request on Android version 8.1 and it worked. I'm getting a content back.

```
    getTest() {
        console.log('test')
      httpModule
        .request({
          url: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080/XXX/XXX",
          method: "GET"
        })
        .then(
          response => {
            // Content property of the response is HttpContent
            // The toString method allows you to get the response body as string.
            const str = response.content.toString();
            const head = response.headers.toString();
            console.log("Content:" + str + " Header: " + head );
            // The toJSON method allows you to parse the received content to JSON object
            // var obj = response.content.toJSON();
            // The toImage method allows you to get the response body as ImageSource.
            // var img = response.content.toImage();
          },
          e => {}
        );
    }
```

Version 8.1 Emulator delivers me the content, but my physical tablet running on Android version 9 only gives the output 'test' to the console. It doesn't event connect to my backend (I configured a logger which gives outputs on requests).

Comment: Please add logcat.

Comment: Update your manifest file with the android:usesCleartextTraffic flag.
<application ... android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" ...>

Comment: Adding the usesCleartextTraffic flag solved my problem! Thank you very much mate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nativescript: HTTP failure response for unknown URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54018049/nativescript-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url)

Comment: Possible but I don't get any error that's the difference.