# Subscribe() method not works in Microsoft Edge

Tags: angular, typescript, observers

I'm using the `subscribe()` to get values in `json` format. This values are displayed in screen.

The problem is in Microsoft Edge this method not works. It's returned error of `HttpResponse` 0. However, in Chrome and Firefox works normally.

This is my code:

```
if (this.machine.length === 0) {
  this.simulatorService.getAks(this.codIm, this.codCS)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log('works!');
        this.machine= data;
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.machine= [];
      }
    );
}
```

So, I need use other method than `.subscribe()`? What?

So, what is the best way to turn my code works on Microsoft Edge?

---------- *UPDATE 1* -----------

This code is my `getAsks`. It's a route that return a json file with some data.

```
  getAsks(codIm: codIm, codCS: codCS): Observable<Array<Equip>> {

    return this.http.get<Array<Equip>>(
      `${this.urlBase}v1/simulator/machine/${codIm}/${codCS}`,
      {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
      });
  }
```

Comment: Would you be able to share the code of `simulatorService.getAks` and the relevant code that initializes `this.machine.length`? Perhaps make a Stackblitz demonstrating the issue.

Comment: I insert the `getAsks` method for better viewing. It's called in html with the click of button.

Comment: Edge may have issues with the `Content-Type` header that you are adding. Is there any reason that you need this header on an HTTP GET request? It is not a standard header for GET.

Comment: It was just standardized. However, even removing the `Content-Type` still does not work on microsoft edge. Do you know what it could be? I get: `Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error` in my log of errors

Comment: The kind/name of erros is correlated with `HttpErrorResponse`. It also appears in my `console`

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180634/i-get-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error-instead-of-actu) with the same error message in Angular? It seems likely to be an error with the server and not the Angular client.

Answer (score 0):

The error invalid HttpResponse is probably because of your api not returning correct headers. So, I suggest for you to check the value of `${this.urlBase}v1/simulator/machine/${codIm}/${codCS}` and if your api is handling this link correctly.