# HttpErrorResponse in Ionic Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to work with Ionic (first attempt) and somehow I'm not able to get my data in my view

#### Code

`Service (posts.service.ts)`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostsService {

  apiUrl = 'https://example.com/api/posts/';
  url: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getPosts(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}`).pipe(
      map(posts => posts)
    );
  }

  getDetails(url) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}?i=${url}&plot=full`);
  }
}
```

`Controller (posts.page.ts)`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PostsService } from './../../services/posts.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.page.scss'],
})
export class PostsPage implements OnInit {

  posts: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private postsService: PostsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

`view (posts.page.html)`

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <div slot="start"></div>
    <img [src]="post.image" />
    {{post.title}}
    <div class="item-note" slot="end">
      {{post.body}}
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

#### Output

`Live API`

[image: one]

`My APP`

[image: two]

Any idea where I did mistake?

Comment: When do you assign `posts` in your controller to the service response?

Comment: @Jojofoulk `PostsService` in `constructor` i think?! this is my first attempt with this framework i followed a tutorial no have idea what's what exactly :)

Comment: You need to call your `getPosts()` in the controller and set the `posts` in your controller to the response of `postsService.getPosts()`. Something like: `this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(res=>this.posts=res.data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

Please refer to my other question which solved this problem.

[Ionic can't get open cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56289595/ionic-cant-get-open-cors)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getPosts()` on your controller.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { PostsService } from './../../services/posts.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.page.scss'],
})
export class PostsPage implements OnInit {

  posts: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private postsService: PostsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
      this.posts = this.postsService.getPosts();
  }

}
```

In your html you also need to specify that is `async`

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
```

Comment: I get this error in console `message: "Http failure response for https://example.com/api/posts/: 0 Unknown Error"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"`

Comment: This url `https://example.com/api/posts/` does't returns data. Is this the url you trying to reach?

Comment: You probably changed the original url to post your question replace `https://example.com/api/posts/` with your original url.

Comment: i know that i am using my real url in services file. for here i just changed my real url to example

Comment: Check if this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180634/i-get-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error-instead-of-actu) is related, looks like a CORS problem

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe the observable to get the result. Observables are Lazy , unless you subscribe , it wont initiate the call.You can use angular **async** pipe which will automatically subscribe and unsubscribe for you

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let post of getPosts() | async">
    <div slot="start"></div>
    <img [src]="post.image" />
    {{post.title}}
    <div class="item-note" slot="end">
      {{post.body}}
    </div>
  </ion-item>
```

or you can subscribe the from the component itself.

```
    posts:any;
    ngOnInit() {
    this.poseService.getPosts().suscribe((res)=>{
      this.posts=res;
    })
    }
 <ion-item *ngFor="let post of posts">
```

Comment: it returns `ERROR TypeError: "_co.getPosts is not a function"`

Comment: @mafortis change your map like map(posts => posts.data)

Comment: I get this error in console `message: "Http failure response for https://example.com/api/posts/: 0 Unknown Error" ​ name: "HttpErrorResponse"`