# Angular2 - send object in http.post request body

Tags: arrays, angular, http, object

I am working on Angular2 web project, in my ts class I have an object :

```
  Object: any=  {
      "first":null,
      "second":null,
      "third": null,
  }
```

I want to send the object in http.post request body. I tried the next code, but it doesnot work;

```
     method() {
       const url='/pathname/';
       return this.http.post(url, this.Object).pipe(map((data:any)=>data));
     }
```

I got an error in console:

```
    error :  HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 400, statusText: "OK",url: "http://localhost:8080/path", ok: false,..}
    headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
    message: "Http failure response for 
    http://localhost:8080/path 400 OK"
    name: "HttpErrorResponse"
    ok: false
    status: 400
    statusText: "OK"
    url: "http://localhost:8080/path"
```

Can you explain me how to send typescript object in post request body ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you `subscribe` to that post request? If yes then does request appear in network tab? It does have body with your object data?

Comment: @Buczkowski  Yes, the request appears in network tab and I can see my object in 'Request Payload' field, but unfrotunately I dont know what does it mean

Comment: @"Yes, the request appears in network tab and I can see my object in 'Request Payload' field" - then what precisely is not working here? Request is being sent with the expected contents, seems like working to me.

Comment: @mbojko I get an error in console and it doesnot return data

Comment: @T.S include error from console

Comment: @T.S error doesn't have much details but it simply means that it's **Bad Request**. There could be several reasons behind but probably request isn't formed well.

Comment: @T.S your back-end returns an error, there is no problem with your code. Maybe `this.Object` does not contain data asked by your backend.

Comment: @youri I've made the request with soapUI and everythins worked fine, I will check this.Object once again, maybe you are right

Comment: 1) Don't name your object UpperCase Object, it already exists in JavaScript as a function. 2) What does your BackEnd return?

Comment: @ritaj Json format data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180634/i-get-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error-instead-of-actu There's your answer.

Comment: @"I've made the request with soapUI and everythins worked fine," - then it's the "spot the difference" game. Compare the correct request with the one sent by your app, every header, and find what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the post observable returned by `method` function. It is done like this.

```
this.method().subscribe(
                 res => {
                 // Handle success response here
                 },
                 err => {
                 // Handle error response here
                 }
              );
```

Comment: The HTTP request should actually be subscribed to in the code that would call the method `method()`, not in the method’s code.

Comment: Thanks Edric for pointing it out. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: The OP subscribed to the observable, his problem is about a **400: bad request**.

Answer (score 0):

you should subscribe the post method because this method of http class returns a observable.
you can rewrite your code as:-

```
 method() {
   const url='/pathname/';
   return this.http.post(url, this.Object).subscribe( resp=> {
               const data = resp; // response you get from serve
          }, error => {
                      console.log(error); //error you get from server 
          });
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

you are getting the 400 bad request error, the payload keys are mis matching with the middle wear. please suggest pass the correct params into Request object.

Comment: Hi Dheeraj, welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider providing a clear and concise explanation to why your answer would help the OP.

Comment: Hello Edric, OP did not subscribed the response thats why i have suggested him to create separate service where he can create methods and subscribe those methods result into their component.

Comment: Hello Edric, he is getting the 400 bad request error, the payload keys are mis matching with the middle wear. please suggest him to pass correct params in the object.