# Laravel API Rest doesn't work in device Android

Tags: android, laravel, ionic-framework, cors, laravel-http-client

I have an app in IONIC and in browser the call to API works but when I run on Android device it shows this error:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "http://192.168.1.***:8080/api/auth/login", ok: false, …}
error: ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
message: "Http failure response for http://192.168.1.***:8080/api/auth/login: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://192.168.1.***:8080/api/auth/login"
__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

In IONIC I send like `API_URL = 'http://192.168.1.***:8080/api/';` to use HttpClient, and in Laravel I run `php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.*** --port 8080`

Please, someone knows what I should do to work?

Comment: code error 0 is a CORS FAILURE ,  maybe this can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180634/i-get-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error-instead-of-actu

Comment: I configured config.xml and network_security_config.xml to allow everthing but doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You don't have to do anything to your IONIC app. You can enable CORS request by adding required headers for that you can create your own middleware in Laravel to handle cors, A sample middleware would be:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{    
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');    
    }
}
```

Then use it, by editing app\Http\Kernel.php

```
 protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
     // middleware for your web routes
    ],
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
        'cors',
    ],

]
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // other middleware code
   'cors' => \EuroKids\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
]
```

You can customize the above middleware as required.

However, if you don't want to do create your own middleware you can use this library:
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: I edited Cors and Kernel, used API_URL = 'http: //192.168.1.***: 8000 / api / again but doesn't work

Comment: I need to edit something in .env? `APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV= local
APP_KEY=base64:IokQpQNAF277VRJSWIUSxJ8iUSOjX5Rv/6U8Cd6HLuo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost`