# Getting error when use Android Koush Ion to call Laravel route

Tags: android, laravel, android-studio, laravel-7, ion-koush

I'm trying to learn android development, I'm using Android Studio. I need to access an external database (to insert, get itens ... CRUD) and I've found a tutorial that tells me to use [koush ion](https://github.com/koush/ion), from Android using Ion, I call a web page that is a [Laravel 7](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x) Route. When I call without parameters, it works very well and I can get in Android the returned value. But when I use "setBodyParameter", I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.gson.JsonElement com.google.gson.JsonObject.get(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

My laravel route just calls this function:

```
function cadastrar(){
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    $resposta = array();
    $myUser = null;

    $nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : 'Teste 2';
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : 'teste@gmail.com';

    $myUser = new Usuario;
    $myUser->nome = $nome;
    $myUser->email = $email;
    $myUser->save();

    $resposta = array('id' => strval($myUser->id_usuario), 'nome' => $myUser->nome, 'email' => $myUser->email);

    return json_encode($resposta);
}
```

My Laravel route is Route::get (but when I change it to Route::post I get an error too).

And my Android code that calls this page is:

```
final TextView txtErro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
txtErro.setText("");
final String strNome = nome.getText().toString();
final String strEmail = email.getText().toString();
String url = "**My URL to the route in laravel**";
Ion.with(MainActivity.this)
     .load(url)
     .setBodyParameter("nome", strNome)
     .setBodyParameter("email", strEmail)
     .asJsonObject()
     .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
         @Override
         public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
             try {
                 txtErro.setText(result.get("id").getAsString());
             } catch (Exception erro) {
                 txtErro.setText(erro.toString());
             }
         }
     });
```

When I comment the two lines of ".setBodyParameter", I get the returned value from laravel (if laravel route is Route::get). When I change the line of "load" to "load("POST", url)", I get an error.

I tried something related to CORS that I found [here in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58915977/laravel-api-rest-doesnt-work-in-device-android) and in my Laravel Kernel.php I commented the line that calls "VerifyCsrfToken", but still didn't working.

(Finally, I'm sorry if have something wrong in my english)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try logging the Exception e and JsonObject result?
or set logging for the request and watch it in logcat

`.setLogging("MyLogs", Log.DEBUG)`