# http failure response for (unknown url) 0 unknown error android in android?

Tags: android, angular, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new in ionic framework. I have worked on IONIC4, Angular. It working fine in **chrome browser** but in **android** got error. I am wasting my time, What should I do?

> http failure response for (unknown url) 0 unknown error android

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180634/i-get-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error-instead-of-actu

Comment: Working in chrome browser. But not in android