# Could not get Node Js server to work on AWS ec2 Instance - Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently ran into a problem with my Node js server side code and ec2.

Basically the problem was that the hardware on which my node js code was hosted had gone into maintenance due to which I had to stop and restart my ec2 instance which I did successfully.

So now the ec2 instance is running properly and I managed to get the node server running but I could not make the request to the server from angular but on postman it is working fine

There is a similar question at [I get "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error" instead of actual error message in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180634/i-get-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error-instead-of-actu) but that didn't work for me either. My cors is set up properly

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Can you post the error as well as the logs when you try to run your node server?

Comment: Hi @JechChua there is no error log. The node server is running fine but I can't make request to it. I am using elastic IP 18.209.143.118.

Comment: I thought you said your node server is not starting?

Comment: My bad, I phrased it wrong. The server is starting but I cannot make request to it in angular. However, on Postman it is working fine. There is a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180634/i-get-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error-instead-of-actu but that solution didn't work out for me