# Http failure response for http://... 0 Unknown Error

Tags: c#, angular, swagger, swagger-codegen

When I am calling my .Net backend from my angular frontend I get the following error:
"Http failure response for http://  0 Unknown Error"

Testing those Backend-Calls with Swagger works perfectly fine and since i have let swaggergen create my services in my angular frontend i asume they are also working.

I have stumbled across Solutions where CORS needed to be added to the Backend Project. After installing and adding the needed CORS lines in the program.cs it still doesn't work.

I have tried simply typing the url into chrome where http://... didn't work https:// delievered the required data but i don't know if that has anything to do with my problem.

Comment: The problem was related to CORS, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180634/i-get-http-failure-response-for-unknown-url-0-unknown-error-instead-of-actu